# Remover elemento de uma lista por chave (key) e por valor (value)

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte lista

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Digamos que quero remover o num 7, por valor e/ou por chave e ficar com:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Como faço?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
val_remove = 7
```

#### [Remover](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) por valor

```
my_list.remove(val_remove)
```

Ter em conta que desta maneira:

- Só remove a primeira ocorrência do elemento, se houverem dois ou mais `val_remove` (7, neste caso) só vai remover o primeiro que encontrar
- Caso o valor não exista na lista vai disparar uma excepção,  caso não a capture é esta:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Para remover a só a primeira ocorrência, sem termos a certeza se o elemento existe dentro da lista:

```
if(val_remove in my_list):
    my_list.remove(val_remove)
```

Para remover todas as ocorrências de `val_remove` (7, neste caso):

```
while val_remove in my_list:
    my_list.remove(val_remove)
```

**Com [filter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) e [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk):**

Se estiver python 2.x, para alcançar o mesmo (remover todas as ocorrências) pode:

```
filter(lambda a: a != val_remove, my_list)
```

Se estiver python 3.x, para alcançar o mesmo (remover todas as ocorrências) pode:

```
list(filter(lambda a: a != val_remove, my_list))
```

#### [Remover](http://www.dotnetperls.com/del-python) por key (chave)

Obviamente tem de saber o index (chave) do valor que quer remover de antemão, neste caso é o 6, então fazemos:

```
del my_list[6]
```

Se index (chave) não existir uma excepção é disparada:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Se não tiver a certeza que o index (chave) existe em `my_list` pode também:

```
my_list = [i for i in my_list if my_list.index(i) != 6] # caso o index (chave) de i for 6 nao e copiado
```

Ter em conta que esta ultima solução não é bem remover, é mais copiar a lista para a mesma variável sem o valor que estava no index do `val_remove` (chave do 7, é a 6, neste caso)

Comment: Ótima explicação. Muito obrigado, fiquei perfeitamente esclarecido

Comment: De nada @AlbertoPimenta

Answer (score 3):

Simples, para remover elementos de uma lista pelo seu valor, basta usar o método `remove`:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> my_list.remove(7)
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Agora, para remover algum elemento de uma lista pelo seu índice, você pode usar o método `pop`:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> my_list.pop(6)
7
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Veja mais sobre como trabalhar com listas em python na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 2):

remove todas as ocorrências desejadas 1+x...

```
def remove_item(my_list,*args):
    deletar = list(args)
    for item in deletar:
        while item in my_list:
            my_list.remove(item)
    return my_list

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,7,8,1,1,100,4]
remove_item(my_list,1,4)
#[2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 100]
my_list = [1,2,3,"erro",4,5,6,2,7,8,1,1,100,4,"erro","PYTHON"]
remove_item(my_list,"erro",100,1)
#[2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 'PYTHON']
```

Comment: Bom tarbalho `+1`. Só mudava de maneira a os items a remover entrassem   na função como uma lista também. Mas é só questão de gosto. `remove_item(my_list, ["erro",100,1])`, dessa maneira até podia apagar `deletar = list(args)`, esta linha